# vxWorks FTP boot error 0x8800dd

Tags: networking, ftp, boot, vxworks, rom

While trying to update the firmware on a device, I bricked it. Now I am trying to boot it via FTP from the vxWorks boot rom.

It successfully connects and downloads the firmware image file from the FTP server but then fails with the following error:

```
Loading... 3
Error loading file: errno = 0x8800dd.
```

vxWorks is not my area so, any help is greatfully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: It turned out that the firmware image which I was trying to load was the problem. I don't know if it was damaged or just the wrong one.

Using another firmware image file, the system downloaded the file and booted properly.